# Using ngen.exe to compile a kernel

Tags: c#, osdev, ngen

I understand that the Cosmos and SharpOS have made their own compilers to build binary code from C#, but could you use Microsoft's .NET AOT to do the same thing? Compiling C# to x86, that is. I assume you would have to leave out using statements, much like OS development when it comes to include statements.
Any feedback appreciated. Thanks

EDIT: The main reason I want to use C# in kernel development is for the memory management that managed code brings with it, especially the single address space property. Would it be necessary to boot a JIT compiler, then compile C#? Or is the environment still too crippled at that point? Thanks for feedback

Comment: You mean you want to write a kernel, but where all the characteristics of kernel developments are handled for you? You'd be better off using an existing kernel then. That's kind of what they're for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: No, using ngen.exe / an [AOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOT_compiler) compiler would not be enough to compile a kernel.

Long answer: ngen.exe / an AOT compiler cuts out the job of the JIT compiler, but the CLR is a lot more than just a JIT compiler - even without referencing any other assemblies it also provides things like memory management, garbage collection, type checking and exception handling (and a whole load of other things besides).

Yes using ngen does take you a step closer to producing a kernel in C#, but it doesn't take you that much closer - you still have a whole load of other problems to solve, ones which are more easily solved by writing a compiler that targets your intended environment (rather than the CLR).

**Update:** If you want the "managed" part of C# then you need to create yourself a managed environment to run your code in, i.e. garbage collector etc... (or try and get an existing on like the CLR to work, which would probably be more difficult).  This is a pretty herculean task even **with** the support of an underlying OS, doing this when you *are* the OS even more so (although by no means impossible - after all this is exactly what projects like Singularity and Cosmos have done).

Comment: I'm not giving up yet, but this does answer the question regarding ngen. Thanks

Comment: @apophis If you are just getting started in kernel development then you should probably start out with a more "traditional" language, like C, C++ or assembly.

Answer (score 0):

No you could not do it with ngen.  The ngen output itself is not low-level enough to bring up a kernel without all the supporting CLR and windows infrastructure being carried along as well.

The other projects you mention compile a subset of the CLR to binary which is a slightly different process.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
C# is a mannaged language, that means it's code(IL code) will be compiled at the runtime... you could write your own compiler that will compile C# into native computer code but this will leave you without a lot of features that .NET has, such as Garbage Collectors, memory mannagment, JIT Compilers, and will be something like C++ just with C# syntax

As an abstract Idea, i think you can create a small CLR alternative with JIT Compilers,  and garbage collectors,that will be ebmedded into your application, but this will increase your application size and you'll need more resources...

Comment: Kind of right but mostly not - when people say that C# is a managed language, they mean that is normally run in the context of a managed environment (like the CLR) but its not the language itself that makes it managed, its the runtime.  Just as you can compile C++ code to IL (known as managed C++) you can (at least in theory) compile C# to a completely native output.

Comment: I think not the managed enviroment makes a language mannaged, but the compiler that compiles into mannaged code, and as I said you could compile into native code, but you will not be able to run CLR features such as garage colectors thereby you should be worried about memory mannagment, and so on, and you'll have to write more code, at least destructors for objects

Answer (score 0):

I found this [resource](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IL2CPU_%28compiler%29) that is using to compile IL to  native code, used in cosmOS project